# Why is the unixODBC-devel package unavailable on our RHEL 7.5 server?

Tags: rhel

We are trying to install the `unixODBC-devel` package on our RHEL 7.5 server. This seems like a common enough package; I've installed more than once on Ubuntu. I see from the RHEL [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/package_manifest/chap-base-server-variant) that it *should* be available.

However it is not listed when I search for it:

```
[user@host ~]$ yum search unixODBC         
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
===== N/S matched: unixODBC =====
opensips-unixodbc.x86_64 : OpenSIPS unixODBC Storage support
erlang-odbc.x86_64 : A library for unixODBC support in Erlang
```

Is unixODBC-devel supposed to be missing, and my assumption that it should be available is wrong? If not, is there a common cause for common packages to be missing like this? Here's info about our system:

```
[user@host ~]$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.5 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.5"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Network"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.5:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.5
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.5"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your system is a Red Hat EL 7 system, you would need a Red Hat subscription to use it and download packages.  If you have a subscription, you can find which repositories you are subscribed to or which subscriptions certain packages are located in using https://access.redhat.com/ with your subscription account.

If you do not have a subscription and do not intend to activate this server with Red Hat, then you should be using a different operating system such as CentOS, which offers all of Red Hat's open source packages without a subscription.

Comment: just to be sure  (since I am not the employee with credentials to https://access.redhat.com): one could even unsubscribe from repositories that contain "core" packages, as listed [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/package_manifest/index)?

Comment: Since you have RedHat 7, it looks like you can use the `subscription-manager` command to check your subscription and available repositories.  If your subscription had expired, you would have lost access to some repositories.